# SQL column heading NUll

Tags: sql, oracle

HI I am going through SQL null values and there is a query

```
select sysdate, 1+5, 'ABC', 'ABC'||null from dual
```

which returns value

```
SYSDATE          1+5  'AB   'AB
---------       ----  ---   ---
10-OCT-15         6   ABC   ABC
```

Please let me know why the heading column is getting trimmed to just 'AB and why null column has a value of ABC. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't given SQL*Plus a name for the column, so it's making one up for you. If you want a name for the column, use an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heading (if not specified manually) is resolved from data type. If only literals are used Oracle determines the type from them. In your case the output is:

NUMBER, VARCHAR2(3), VARCHAR2(3)

so SQL*Plus uses the heading of A3 and the remaining part is truncated.

Concatenation operator behaves differently from other operators, value || NULL results to value, not NULL. In other RDBMS, like SQL Server + is used to concatenate strings and has an option to set its behavior so it might be both value and NULL.

Comment: No - the heading is derived from the column expression, not from the data type. Doesn't matter if it's a number, varchar2, date, or whatever.

Comment: I meant the column heading format of course, not the actual title.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your behaviour:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/8290/0)**

```
select sysdate, 1+5, 'ABC', 'ABC'||null
from dual;
```

Result:

```
╔════════════════════════════╦══════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║          SYSDATE           ║ 1+5  ║ 'ABC'  ║ 'ABC'||NULL ║
╠════════════════════════════╬══════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ October, 10 2015 18:49:55  ║   6  ║ ABC    ║ ABC         ║
╚════════════════════════════╩══════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

But you really should allias your calculated column like:

```
select 
  sysdate      AS current_date_time,
  1+5          AS addition,
  'ABC'        AS my_string,
  'ABC'||null  AS my_string2
from dual;
```

Comment: Please have a look at this site where the same result is produced. In my system I am using sqlplus.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Table/SELECTINGFROMDUAL.htm

Comment: @SeshaSwarup Don't depend on expression name, use alliases

Comment: In SQL*Plus scripts is better to set up the headings manually because the heading is resolved from the column data type, not alias. In SELECT 'X' ALIAS FROM DUAL the heading will be resolved as A.

Comment: @Husqvik Good to know.